# split method not working properly in java script?

Tags: javascript, split

i need out put like "naveen","reddy". i am converting string array to string

```
var rows = $scope.CoverageRequirementsOptions.rowData;
console.log(rows);
var data=[]; 
var data1;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {         
    data.push(rows[i].name);  data["naveen","reddy"]`
    data1=data.join(); 
    data1="naveen,reddy" , data["naveen","reddy"]
    data1.split(",");
}

console.log(data1); data1="naveen,reddy"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why for loop? You can do it easily using:

```
var data="naveen,reddy";
var splitted=data.split(',');
console.log(splitted);
```

Split function takes **delimiter as an argument**.

For your question it's ***","*** .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rows` contains the array `["naveen", "reddy"]`, then all you need to output the string `"naveen, reddy"` is the [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function.

var rows = $scope.CoverageRequirementsOptions.rowData;

console.log(rows.join(','); // Outputs "naveen,reddy"